# How to pull words with spaces and number in Regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have following couple of lines:

- The Great Gatsby (1925) by F. Scott Fitzgerald is a short novel which takes.
- Fight Club is a 1996 novel by Chuck Palahniuk.

I have to pick writer name that comes after *by* and year it was written; 1925 and 1996 respectively. What I figured, I need a couple of RegEx; one for picking numbers only by doing `\d+` and other for picking writer name. For Writer I made this regex(https://regex101.com/r/Z55yz3/1) but it is not working as it should due to presence of `.` and space.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kumarrishikesh12/Pama9/24/ ... This Is For Year Find

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar I can find year simply by doing `\d+` as well. No need for such long code.

Comment: `#(by)\s*(.*)\.?#g` for writer name you may try this :-) https://regex101.com/r/Z55yz3/4

Comment: @hassan pretty close. The only issue is that it is also picking `(1925)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Z55yz3/7 or so https://regex101.com/r/Z55yz3/8 if thinking that all words in name begin with uppers

Comment: @splash58 it did trick. Yes all names begin from Cap words. Can you make it an answer?

Comment: Fine. I've written the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[0-9]{4}` -  takes 4-digits number

`\bby` - gets word 'by' and

`(?:\s+[A-Z][\w.]+)+`- selects following words and abbreviations, beginning with uppercase letter

```
([0-9]{4}).*(?:\bby)((?:\s+[A-Z][\w.]+)+)
```

**[Demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Z55yz3/8)**

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex `/^.+?\ BY (.+)$/is` like this

```
$string_text = 'The Great Gatsby (1925) by F. Scott Fitzgerald is a short novel which takes.';
preg_match("/^.+?\ BY (.+)$/is" , $string_text, $match);
echo $match[1];
```